# Did I enter my digital ID in Hytera PD785G?

Tags: dmr, hytera

Some time ago, I set up my Hytera PD785G. Unfortunately, I can't remember whether I have only requested my digital ID (I can look it up [on ham-digital.org](https://ham-digital.org/dmr-userreg.php?callsign=dk3tu)) or whether I have also entered it into the radio.

How do I look up the digital ID in order to find out whether it's entered and entered correctly? If it can't be looked up, where would I enter it?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is if you send a private call to 9990 (parrot) in brandmaister network and see the actual traffic on brandmaister's site.